# How to make subscribeNext block fire after every chained observable onNext event

Tags: swift, uikit, reactive-programming

The user must be able to print a set of items they've selected from a table.

I have a `PrintEngine` class that creates a flow of `Observable<Report>`. The user queues up a bunch of items they want to print, then the `PrintEngine` just calls `PrintEngine.print(items)`. Each one of these steps is asynchronous and depends on the other:

```
Request the items -> Show Printer Picker UI -> Print the items -> Acknowledge the items have been printed
```

I currently have the flow working, because each of my network requests returns an observable `Report` which contains the information shared between the steps of the process. I call:

```
class PrintEngine {
     static print(items: [Item]) -> Observable<Report> {
         return request(items).flatMap(pickPrinter).flatMap(print).flatMap(acknowledge)
     }
     // ...
     static func request(items: [Item]) -> Observable<Report> {...} // network call to get pdf data
     static func pickPrinter(report: Report) -> Observable<Report> {...} // UIPrinterPickerController UI asynchrony
     static func print(report: Report) -> Observable<Report> {...} // Printing the actual data
     static func acknowledge(report: Report) -> Observable<Report> {...} // network call to notify server of print outcome
}
```

Call site in my View Controller:

```
@IBAction func printQueue() {
    // `items` is from the View Controller
    PrintEngine.print(items).subscribeNext { _ in
        print("External On Next.")
    }
}
```

But this only prints

```
"External On Next."
```

Rather than

```
"External On Next."
"External On Next."
"External On Next."
"External On Next."
```

## How do I make it so that my `subscribeNext` block fires after every `onNext` event in my flow?